# Holding Super key doesn't show the number of the last unpinned app

Tags: launcher, 13.10

Do I need to file this as a bug? Look on the picture below:

[image: 13.10 launcher]

As you can see, I'm on 13.10 Live USB session. When I hold the SUPER key, the last app on the launcher doesn't show the 'number' to press to get focus on it . I even tried to do SUPER + '6' to see if it will focus the Calc app but nothing happens . But if I'm going to lock the 5th app (TextEditor) on the launcher, the last app (Calc) will show number '6' on it and I will be able to get focus onto it . But then again even the 5th app on the image (TextEditor) is not a pinned app on the launcher so why does shortcut-number appears on it .

I'm using 13.10 amd64 bit OS .

Comment: seems like a bug if this worked otherwise in 13.04 (I don't have earlier than 13.10 atm

Comment: @doug , do you also experience this on your 13.10?

Comment: yes, but I was able to ck. 13.04 where it also happens so maybe that's the way it works??

Comment: hmmm, i just tried 13.04 but I don't experience this problem . in your 13.04 session, try to remove other pinned apps on your launcher and at least leave 3 locked apps on it . then open 2 apps from dash that are not on your launcher . when you hold down SUPER key, you'll see that all the apps have numbers on it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug answers it all: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/778499

sadly it was happening since 11.04 ..